# PHP генератор случайных чисел

Tags: php

Вопрос по поводу линейного конгруэнтного алгоритма. Если известно около 40-50 чисел подряд выданными генератором с m=16. Как можно вычислить A и C по этим данным и можно ли вообще? Сколько это примерно займёт времени?

Comment: Ну если A<m, C<m, то считать вам 16*16 вариантов. Меньше чем за секунду посчитаете. Если внутреннее состояние известно, конечно.

Comment: A и C больше m.

Comment: Тогда нельзя предсказать сколько времени займет. Полный перебор всех состояний генератора, A и C определенно поможет.

Comment: А если указать переменной A значение к примеру "5412589", восстановить одинаковое С для всех чисел возможно? Или нужно и A и C?

Comment: И какие вообще есть способы, чтобы такое реализовать?

Comment: Читать что вам пишут попробуйте, для начала: "Полный перебор всех состояний генератора, A и C"

Comment: Полный стандартный перебор может занять очень очень много времени. Есть ли какие-то варианты кроме полного перебора?

Comment: Ну есть вариант использовать статистику - линейную регрессию. Построить модель на основе существующих данных и попытаться предсказать новые значения. В R можно реализовать. А так и не знаю даже...